# Workbench showing extra picklist value..Confused!

Tags: custom-field, picklist, workbench

I recently changed the picklist values from **open, ship, invoiced, rejected** TO  **open, ship, deliver, cancel**.

If I check in detail field page, I can see the new 4 values, but when I query from workbench as...

> select status__c from order__c group by status__c

I strangely get 5 values :O

**Open, Ship, Deliver, Cancel, Reject**

Why did the extra field appear? I did this using the following ways...

1)   Directly changed the values and replaced in prod

2)   Migrated from sandbox to prod

I'm confused. Any suggestion would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any data in your sandbox that was saved with the previous previous values?

Comment: No the sandbox has the same new values and migration was successful too.

Comment: @crmprogdev hit it on the nose -- the SOQL query will return values from the database, regardless of the field's picklist value definition.  Picklists are simply a way for SFDC UI to mediate what is entered by a user. They do not enforce valid values on records in the database.

Comment: Can you try using Rest Explorer in workbench to check the number of fields via the Tooling API. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @varunguruvugari it would be great if u could tell me how to. Thanks

Comment: hey @MnZ 
Go to Workbench, Give your ORG details and then go to Utilities --> Rest Explorer and give this query
/services/data/v32.0/tooling/query/?q=Select Id, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix, TableEnumOrId From CustomField Where TableEnumOrId = '' 
(give your object id on which the custom field is) and say execute. You will know how many picklist values are there.

Comment: @varunguruvugari its not working